# Store plots in an array

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am trying to plot histograms of different columns of a dataframe in subplots.

```
plt_count = 1
for i = names(abalone)[2:end]
    p[plt_count]=histogram(abalone[:,i])
    plt_count += 1
end
plot(p, layout=(3,3), legend=false)
```

This is what I tried. But I can't come up with the right definition for the array `p`. How do I define p?

Improvements to the code will also be helpful.

Comment: What plotting package do you use?

Comment: I am using the `Plots` package

Comment: In Plots.jl you can simply write `histogram(Matrix(abalone[:,2:end]), layout=(3,3), legend=false)` or if you be a bit more memory efficient `histogram(Matrix(@view abalone[:,2:end]), layout=(3,3), legend=false)`.

Comment: Ok. OKay. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the type stability, you can make `Any` type array.

```
ps = Array{Any}(nothing, 3)
ps[1] = plot([2,3,4])
ps[2] = plot([1,5])
ps[3] = plot([10,5,1,0])

@show typeof(ps)
plot(ps..., layout=(3,1))
```

If you want to create an array of `Plot` type specifically, one approach is to initialize an array with a dummy plot, then replace later.

```
ps = repeat([plot(1)], 3)
ps[1] = plot([2,3,4])
ps[2] = plot([1,5])
ps[3] = plot([10,5,1,0])

@show typeof(ps)
plot(ps..., layout=(3,1))
```